# Defining custom syntax highlighting for Atlassian Fisheye/Crucible: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, syntax-highlighting

I am using Atlassian Fisheye/Crucible ("fecru") for MATLAB code review and fecru is obviously missing a syntax scheme support for matlab code. Apparently there is a mechanism to support a user-defined scheme, one just has to place it into folder *syntax/..* and register in *filename.map* (also see [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/Defining+your+own+syntax+highlighting+in+Crucible+or+Fisheye)).

Maybe some one has already implemented **matlab.def** file? Would appreciate if you can share it.

For now my best starting point is **java.def**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to produce a somewhat modified **python.def** to highlight MATLAB syntax on jsp-side of fecru:

Put [this](https://gist.github.com/ewiger/4969758) into **matlab.def**

```
syntaxdef matlab {
 ...
}
```

and link it in **filename.map**

```
"**/*.m" matlab.def "MATLAB"
```

make sure it does not conflict with

```
# "**/*.m" objc.def "Objective C"
```

You will have to restart fecru for changes to take place.